# Creating a custom DateTime field for a RoR form

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3.1, erb

I'm trying to implement a custom DateTime field with three text fields (One linked to a JS datepicker and two others for the hours and the minutes)

I want the fields to be connected if possible.

```
<%= f.text_field :date_time, :class => "datepicker" %><br />
<%= f.text_field :date_time["hours"] %>
<%= f.text_field :date_time["minutes"] %>
```

Can it ever work or must I do all the processing when instantiating the object ?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will need to build a time in Ruby when receiving the form.

Ideally use something like:

```
<%= text_field_tag 'date', :class => "datepicker" %><br />
<%= text_field_tag "hours" %>
<%= text_field_tag "minutes" %>
```

You'll then need to parse the date to get the year/month/day value and then use these with your hour/minute values and stuff them into Date.civil_with_format to get a Time object back.

Comment: I've done this way, but I was still wondering if there was something more ruby-ish to do this. Thanks for answer

Comment: There could be, but you'd be writing your own date_time_select